# Downloading cross platform

Tags: downloads

I am trying to download Ubuntu for PCs (64-bit), but the computer I need to put it on isn't working so I'm trying to use my MacBook, but every time I try to download it I get the Mac version.  Does anyone know how I can download the PC version to disk using my Mac?

Comment: Use this [link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso).

Comment: that link is still making the amd64 version download.

Comment: It exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the 64bit, then it is correct. Unless is says specifically amd64 MAC, then it is correct. here is a link for the 64bit if for whatever reason your computer is not letting you select that http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.04&architecture=amd64

Answer (score 0):

There is NO "mac" version of Ubuntu. It is just "Ubuntu for either i386 (32-bit) or x86_64/amd64 (64-bit)."

Once you have downloaded the requisite file, make sure you have the complete file (check the md5 sum). Then, put it onto a USB stick/thumb-drive using the "longish" procedure outlined here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Take that USB stick/thumb-drive to your "not working" PC and start that PC with the USB stick/thumb-drive plugged in. You should be on your way to running/installing Ubuntu on your "not-working" PC.

(Could you please explain what you mean by "not-working" PC? Thx!)

HTH!

Comment: The non working computer is running incredibly slow and freezes whatever program i'm trying to run 70% of the time.  i spent about 3 hours downloading the file on that computer to no affect as I can't burn a dvd on it since it freezes too much.  i'm trying now to save the file to a hard drive since i don't have any dvd's on hand to make a boot disk and can't find any thumb drives.  the last time i tried this i had to download the file directly to the hard drive as i couldn't copy it once it was on the working computer.

Comment: Just finished downloading, was supposed to go straight to hard drive and didn't.  can't copy it to hard drive either.

Comment: the instructions on how to save it to a USB drive don't seem to work as I can't get the file converted to an IMG file.  Followed the exact instructions in the link you gave me and couldn't make it work (yes i did substitute the actual file path for source and destination)

Comment: ignore the non-working computer for now. don't download on that system. download the 64-bit ubuntu onto your mac. then follow the instructions I had linked to to put that ubuntu-64-bit-iso image onto a usb pen-drive. once you have that, insert the usb drive into the "non-working" computer and boot that "non-working" computer from the usb pen-drive. hopefully things should work after that.

Comment: the file is not converting. like i said, i'm following the instructions but obviously not doing something right and i don't know what.

Comment: hdiutil convert /Users/Kelsar/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso -format UDRW -o /Users/Kelsar/Desktop/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.img   this finally got the file converted.  now i just have to find a drive (empty) that i can use to write it on as none of the ones i have now are writeable.  thanks for the help